# Remove first row from file with shell script using if statement

Tags: shell

There are some data files being imported with header names on the first row and others dont have headers. The ones that are with headers are having always "company" as first field on the first row. For loading them into DB I need to get rid of the first row. So I need to write .sh scrict that deletes first row only of those files that have first column first row="company". I guess I need to combine awk with if statement but I dont know exactly how.

Answer (score 1):

```
if  head -n 1 input.csv | cut -f 1 -d ',' | grep company
    then tail -n +2 input.csv > output.csv
else
    cp input.csv output.csv
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the string "company" appears only as 1st field on headers, you can go this way

```
sed -e /^company,/d  oldfile > newfile
```

supposing the separator is a comma.

Another solution :

```
if [ head -1 oldfile | grep -q "^company,"] ; then
   sed -e 1d oldfile > newfile
else
   cp oldfile newfile
fi
```

Comment: Or `sed '1{/^company/d}' file` to make sure, `company` is on first line.

Answer (score 1):

No `if` needed.  Just do it straight forward as you stated your requirements:

Print the first line unless it starts with `company`:

```
strip_header_if_present() {
    IFS='' read -r first_line
    echo "$first_line" | grep -v ^company,
```

Now print the remaining lines:

```
    cat
}
```

To use this shell function:

```
strip_header_if_present < input.csv > output.csv
```